# Windows 2008 R2 Permissions of mapped drive between desktop and server

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

My Desktop is Windows 7 and my Server is Windows 2008 R2...

On my desktop I'm just a standard domain user.
On the server I'm part of the Administrators group.

I map a drive to my server in Windows explorer \\xxxx\c$

I then copy a file from my desktop to the server.

When I log into the server and try to modify the file it won't let me. Notepad will popup asking to save as another file. If i go back to my desktop and edit the file through the mapped drive I can do it without a problem.

Is there a way to be able to copy/modify files and folders to the server without having to go in and fix permissions all the time?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions on the file on the server to confirm that it is in fact a permissions issue?

Comment: The file has SYSTEM (Full Control), Administrators (Full Control), Users (Read Execute, Read) The Group Users has MYDOMAIN/Domain Users in it which I pretty sure I'm part of also. So i guess Windows 2008 is picking the lowest policy?

Comment: Your problem is UAC.  Windows filters your `Administrators` group membership away from you when the UAC is enabled.

Comment: What are the effective permissions on the file for the user in question?

Comment: The specific user does not have permissions to the file. But the user is Administrator and also part of the Users groups see above for permissions. UAC on Windows 7 or Windows 2008?

Comment: Or I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

As Zoredache has said, your problem is UAC while logged on to the server.

You can run Notepad as Administrator (find the Notepad icon in the Start menu, Right-click it and select `Run as administrator`), then open the file in question via `File -> Open`. This will allow you to save the file to it's current location.

An alternative would be to create a folder in the root of C:\, set permissions the way you want, making sure to force inheritance for children, and copy your files there.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to do this all the time. The whole point of me being Administrator on the machine is so I can modify the file. Not do magic voodoo (set permissions or run as admin) all the time I copy files over or create new folders.

I'm logged into the physical machine so why have to do all that?

Comment: Actually the whole point of being Administrator on the server is so that you can perform tasks which regular users cannot (install and manage roles and features). You _can_ edit the files in question, but need to abide by the security policies and framework to do so.
Besides, you don't _really_ need to log on to the actual machine to do it. You say you can edit the file without UAC prompts or being asked to save it to a new location when you do it from your PC, so why not just do that?